# Intel CPU stepping - naming convention

Tags: grub2, grub, cpu, intel, iommu

I'm having trouble enabling IOMMU on Centos 8 (4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64) and I'm starting to think that my CPU doesn't support VT-d.

On the [Intel ARK page for my CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/63697/intel-core-i7-3930k-processor-12m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html) it says "yes" for VT-x and VT-d but there is also the following sentence:

> This product includes VT-d support only on the C2 stepping. Stepping information can be viewed via the menu on the left.

I have no idea what the "menu on the left" is" but if I look for the stepping of my CPU I get the following:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep stepping
stepping    : 7
```

**My question:**

Does "stepping 7" comes **before** or **after** "stepping C2"?

---

More info:

I have the following UEFI settings:

- Intel Virtualization Technology: Enabled
- Intel(R) I/OAT: Disabled
- Intel(R) VT-d: Enabled
- and everything else enabled (except Limit CPUID Maximum which is Disabled)

To check if IOMMU is enabled I tried:

```
$ dmesg | grep -E "DMAR|IOMMU"
```

and

```
$ virt-host-validate
```

which returns:

> ARN (IOMMU appears to be disabled in kernel. Add intel_iommu=on to kernel cmdline arguments)

Settings I tried to append to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in `/etc/default/grub`:

- `intel_iommu=on`
- `intel_iommu=on iommu=pt`
- `intel_iommu=on iommu=pt iommu=1`

Then apply the changes to grub with:

```
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and

```
$ sudo dracut --regenerate-all --force
```